# Dependency Injection or instantiating database class object

Tags: php, dependency-injection

this may seem like a broad question, but what are the practical uses of dependency injection vs instantiating the class inside a `__construct()` call?

I essentially instantiate my database object like this in classes that require it:

```
class Example {
    private $db;

    function __construct() {
        $this->db = db::instance();
    }
}
```

I've used dependency injection in the past and don't know if it's fine to simply share the resource, take the following for example from a `Model`.

```
Class ExampleModel extends Model {

    function do_something() {
        $user = new User($db);
        $user->do_some_stuff();
    }
}
```

So what would be more beneficial to use? Are there any performance related pros/cons? If you need more clarification to the questions, please ask.

---

There is a lot of positive & negative views on Dependency Injection:

- [Dependency Injection is EVIL](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/dependency-injection-is-evil.html)
- [Dependency Injections Pros/Cons/Questions](https://gist.github.com/r00k/3105024)
- [Dependency Injection discourages object orientated programming](http://www.warski.org/blog/2010/10/dependency-injection-discourages-object-oriented-programming/)

---

For anyone interested, this is what the `db::instance()` looks like:

```
public static function instance() {
    if (!self::$instance) {
        $config = get_config();

        self::$instance = new self(
                $config['database']['host'], $config['database']['user'], $config['database']['pass'], $config['database']['db']
        );
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

Comment: Without knowing the particulars of the `db::instance()` function, I can't say for sure but I'd guess that it is not actually creating a new instance every time but actually returning the same instance of your db connection whenever and wherever it's called. This may be the 'singleton' pattern in which you never have more than one instance of your db connection, you just reuse it everywhere in your app. It's probably obvious that this could save some memory and also avoids constructing that object more than once. The savings there will depend on the class in question.

Comment: For me, if you inject the dependency then `Example` doesn't need to know what the class is. If you instantiate it, then it does.

Comment: @scrowler are there any obvious reasons as to why you'd use either? Also, many of the dependency injection "examples" explicitly set the type, i.e. -> `__construct(Db $db) {....`. Is that the norm?

Comment: Yeah - that's totally the norm. You don't need to know who `$db` is, but `Db` might be an interface that `$db` implements, so you will at least know that `$db` is going to abide by a set of rules. If you instantiate the `$db` class explicitly then you have to reference the exact class that it will be.

Comment: @scrowler Excellent! If you want to post that as an answer, I'll gladly accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarising my comments - for me, if you inject the dependency then `Example` doesn't need to know what the class you're injecting is. If you instantiate the class from within `Example` then you need to know exactly what the class is.

Is this a problem/benefit? Depends on you, your preferences and your application. I tend to prefer the more abstract approach.

For example, if you did the following:

```
class Example {
    public function __construct(Injected $inj) {
        $this->db = $inj;
    }
}
```

... you can see that you type hint what you are expecting `$inj` to be. This can either be the type of the class that `$inj` directly is, or an interface that `$inj` implements - in which case you will know that `$inj` adheres to a set of instructions that you expect.

Take the following example:

```
interface Db {
    public function fetch();
    public function insert();
}

class MyDb implements Db {
    public function fetch() {
        // ...
    }
    public function insert() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you type hint the interface in your `Example` class, you don't need to know that `$inj` is a `MyDb` class, but that it implements `Db` - the important part is knowing that the class will follow a defined set of rules (an interface) e.g. that is will implement a `fetch()` and an `insert()` function. Nevermind the actual class - you just want the content.

```
class Example {
    public function __construct(Db $inj) {
        var_dump(get_class($inj)); // string(4) "MyDb"
    }
}
```

This is all an example of injection and its benefits. The equivalent for direct instantiation would mean that your `Example` needs to know about `MyDb`:

```
class Example {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new MyDb; // implements Db, but you need to know exactly
                              // what the class is
    }
}
```

This method removes your flexibility for changing `MyDb` to `YourDb` without having to change the `Example` class.

Again, depends on your situation. If your application has the likelihood to change or has flexibility within components, you might want to use injection. If it's reasonably static then you could instantiate directly.

My final comment would be that when you are unit testing your code, it's much easier to mock an injected object than a directly instantiated one.